# When I update Advanced Custom Fields: Font Awesome Field plugin in WordPress then whole website shows a 403 fatal error

Tags: wordpress

When I update Advanced **Custom Fields: Font Awesome Field** plugin in WordPress then the whole website shows a 403 fatal error. What can I do?

Comment: What have you tried doing? Have you tried enabling PHP errors to see if that provides more information? How about contacting the plugin author?

Comment: Do you know the 403 substatus code? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403